# LocalizedStringKey interpolated with the value of another LocalizedStringKey

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have keys and values in Localizable.strings of this kind:

```
"turn_off_feature_format" = "Turn off %@";
"feature_1_title" = "Feature 1";
"feature_2_title" = "Feature 2";
```

(I can't rename keys to match the values because they're used on other platforms and older UIKit code as well.)

To avoid raw strings copy-pasting, I use the keys as properties of a `LocalizedStringKey` extension. E.g.:

```swift
extension LocalizedStringKey {
  static let feature1Title = Self("feature_1_title")
}
```

A usage example is just `Text(.feature1Title)`.

The tricky part that I haven't figured out comes with strings with placeholders which hold a place for another localized string, like `"turn_off_feature_format"`.

I found one way to deal with it:

```swift
extension LocalizedStringKey {
  static var turnOffFeature1: Self {
    LocalizedStringKey(stringLiteral: String(
      format: String(localized: "turn_off_feature_format"), 
      String(localized: "feature_1_title")
    ))
  }
  static var turnOffFeature2: Self {
    LocalizedStringKey(stringLiteral: String(
      format: String(localized: "turn_off_feature_format"), 
      String(localized: "feature_2_title")
    ))
  }
}
```

This works but has an obvious disadvantage of the hardcoded `"turn_off_feature_format"` key which needs to be copy-pasted to multiple places.

Is there a way to re-write `turnOffFeature1` and `turnOffFeature2` re-using `LocalizedStringKey`'s properties from the extension?

```swift
extension LocalizedStringKey {
  static let turnOffFeature1 = // ...
  static let turnOffFeature2 = // ...
  private static let feature1Title = Self("feature_1_title")
  private static let feature2Title = Self("feature_2_title")
  private static let turnOffFeatureFormat = Self("turn_off_feature_format")
}
```

Or maybe there's a better way of dealing with this that I'm missing?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the localised string has format specifiers, you should also add the format specifiers to the key.

```
// .strings:

"turn_off_feature_format %@" = "Turn off %@";
"feature_1_title" = "Feature 1";
"feature_2_title" = "Feature 2";
```

Thanks to the custom string interpolation provided by [`LocalizedStringKey.StringInterpolation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/localizedstringkey/stringinterpolation), this allows you to directly format the string when creating a `LocalizedStringKey`.

```
// this creates a LocalizedStringKey corresponding to 
// the "turn_off_feature_format %@" key in the .strings file,
// with the placeholder replaced with whatever "feature" is
let key: LocalizedStringKey = "turn_off_feature_format \(feature)"
```

If `feature` is a `LocalizedStringResource`, *it* will get localised too.

Knowing that, we can write something like this:

```
extension LocalizedStringKey {
    static func turnOff(feature: LocalizedStringResource) -> LocalizedStringKey {
        "turn_off_feature_format \(feature)"
    }
}

extension LocalizedStringResource {
    static let feature1 = Self("feature_1_title")
    static let feature2 = Self("feature_2_title")
}
```

(Also consider making an enum to represent the features)

Then you can create `Text`s like this:

```
Text(.turnOff(feature: .feature1))
Text(.turnOff(feature: .feature2))

// this also works:
Text(.feature1)
```

---

If you can't change the localisation keys, I think you are stuck with using `String(format:_:)` to do the formatting. I'm not sure why you are struggling to get rid of the duplicate string literal though. It can just be extracted to another computed property:

```
var format: String {
    String(localized: "turn_off_feature_format")
}
```

```
extension LocalizedStringKey {
  static var turnOffFeature1: Self {
    LocalizedStringKey(stringLiteral: String(
      format: format, 
      String(localized: "feature_1_title")
    ))
  }
  static var turnOffFeature2: Self {
    LocalizedStringKey(stringLiteral: String(
      format: format, 
      String(localized: "feature_2_title")
    ))
  }
}
```

That said, it doesn't make sense for these to be `LocalizedStringKey`s anymore, since you don't actually have a keys called `Turn off Feature 1` etc. These should just be `String`s. I would put them in an enum:

```
enum Features: String {
    case feature1 = "feature_1_title"
    case feature2 = "feature_2_title"
    
    private static var format: String {
        String(localized: "turn_off_feature_format")
    }
    
    var turnOffLocalized: String {
        String(
            format: Self.format,
            String(localized: .init(rawValue))
        )
    }
    
    // for getting only the names of the features
    var key: LocalizedStringKey {
        .init(rawValue)
    }
}
```

e.g.

```
Text(Features.feature1.key)
Text(Features.feature1.turnOffLocalized)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but, as I mentioned in the question, unfortunately I can't rename keys and add placeholders there – the keys are already in use in UIKit as `NSLocalizedString`s and also shared between multiple apps on multiple platforms (not only Apple.)

Comment: @lazarevzubov Okay, then I think you are stuck with `String(format:)`... If you just want to get rid of the string literal duplication, how about putting `String(localized: "turn_off_feature_format")` into a computed property? Instead of `LocalizedStringKey` everywhere, just write a bunch of `String`-typed computed properties.

Comment: I guess this is my best option then. Thank you.